# How to select values out of radio buttons and put them in a PHP Variable

Tags: php

I'm making a Quiz. And with each question I'm showing the possible answers( "True" or "False") with a While loop in PHP:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='quizCheck.php'>";
while(x=0;x<=10; x++){
      echo "<div class='buttons'>
                <label>True
                    <input type='radio' name='answer' value='true' />
                </label> 
                <label>False
                    <input type='radio' name='answer' value='false' />
                </label>
             </div>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

Let's say there are 10 questions and I select "True" on 6 questions.

What code do I have to put in quizCheck.php so it can count the number of "True" answers and store it in a variable?

Comment: you can't. your html is on the client browser, and php runs on the server. you cannot directly access/execute PHP code from the browser, period. at most you can do a form submission/ajax request back to the server and have some code that saves your data server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do two things, first you need a submit button in the form:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Then you will also need the names of the radio inputs to be unique so in the while loop (which you really should just change to a for loop) do:

```
for(x=0;x<=10; x++){
      echo "<div class='buttons'>
                <label>True
                    <input type='radio' name='answer{$x}' value='true' />
                </label> 
                <label>False
                    <input type='radio' name='answer{$x}' value='false' />
                </label>
             </div>";
}
```

When the form is submitted, then in quizCheck.php you just check `$_POST[answer0]` through `$_POST[answer9]` to see which are true and increment a counter.

If you want the answers in a single array then do this:

```
for(x=0;x<=10; x++){
      echo "<div class='buttons'>
                <label>True
                    <input type='radio' name='answers[$x]' value='true' />
                </label> 
                <label>False
                    <input type='radio' name='answers[$x]' value='false' />
                </label>
             </div>";
}
```

When this form is submitted, then in quizCheck.php you just get something like `$answers = $_POST[answers]` and then go through `answers[0]` to `answers[9]` for example

Comment: Hi, I used x=0; etc. in my post, to make the question easier. I actually use the while loop to get the questions out of a database and show them. How can I store the answers in a variable without using the While loop for unique radio input names?

Comment: So either way you are going to have to have some counter, whether its in a for loop or a separate one you make and use inside the while loop. Then you can either do it how I suggested above or throw the answers into a single array